# Exception when insert records into 3 tables within transaction using slick-plain SQL for play2

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

My scenario is as below:

1. There are 3 tables (user, security, password) in my PG DB.
2. When the end use tries to register self into my database, the code will check if the use exists in the user table.
3. If exists, just return a None. otherwise, insert records into (user, security, password)  within the same transaction.

The following is my code:

```
def selectUserCountQuery1(user: User): DBIO[Int] = {
  sql"""SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE provider_id = ${user.providerId} AND phone_num = ${user.phoneNumber}""".as[Int].head
}


def insertUserQuery(user: User): DBIO[Int] = {
    sqlu"""INSERT INTO users VALUES (${user.userId}, ${user.deviceToken},${user.phoneNumber},${user.providerId},
        ${user.gender},${user.email},${user.createTime},${user.loginName},${user.nickName},${user.currentPlatform},${user.roles},${user.avatarUrl})"""
}

def insertPasswordQuery(passwordInfo: PasswordInfo): DBIO[Int] = {
  sqlu"""INSERT INTO password_info VALUES (${passwordInfo.userId}, ${passwordInfo.hasher},
         ${passwordInfo.passwordHash}, ${passwordInfo.salt})"""
}

def insertSecurityTokenQuery(accessToken: UserSecurityToken): DBIO[Int] = {
  sqlu"""INSERT INTO user_security_token VALUES (${accessToken.userId}, ${accessToken.platform},
         ${accessToken.token}, ${accessToken.token_time})"""
}


def registerUser (user: User, password: String): Future[Option[UserProfile]] = {
  val passwordHash = MD5PasswordGenerator.generateMD5WithEncoder(password)
  val passwordInfo : PasswordInfo = PasswordInfo(user.userId, Some("MD5"), passwordHash, Some(""))
  val tokenStr: String = JwtTokenSecurity.jwtTokenString(user.userId, user.currentPlatform)
  val accessToken : UserSecurityToken = UserSecurityToken(user.userId, user.currentPlatform, tokenStr, 1)

  val actions = for {
    count <- selectUserCountQuery1(user) if count == 0
    status1 <- insertUserQuery(user)
    status2 <- insertPasswordQuery(passwordInfo)
    status3 <- insertSecurityTokenQuery(accessToken)
  } yield(count)

  db.run(actions.transactionally).map {
    count  => count match {
      case 0 => Some(UserProfile.user2UserProfile(user, passwordInfo, accessToken))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

The code could work when the user register the information at the 1st time, but will throw errors at 2nd time. (should return None to service).

The error is :

```
--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] - play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider - Shutdown application default Akka system: application
[warn] - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout is greater than connectionTimeout, setting validationTimeout to connectionTimeout.
[info] - play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
do something before the action is executed
[warn] - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout is greater than connectionTimeout, setting validationTimeout to connectionTimeout.
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Action.withFilter failed
  at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anonfun$withFilter$1.apply(DBIOAction.scala:94) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anonfun$withFilter$1.apply(DBIOAction.scala:94) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[error] - application - 

! @6n1mk1oih - Internal server error, for (POST) [/register] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NoSuchElementException: Action.withFilter failed]]
  at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.api.mvc.WithFilters.onError(Filters.scala:93) [play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:273) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:269) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Action.withFilter failed
  at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anonfun$withFilter$1.apply(DBIOAction.scala:94) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anonfun$withFilter$1.apply(DBIOAction.scala:94) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146) ~[slick_2.11.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
  … 13 common frames omitted
```

It is so weird there is no exception if I get rid of Guard condition (count ==0). But the user information will be inserted into the database constantly.

Would any experts help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guard `DBIO.withFilter` works like `Future.withFilter`: not matching the predicate fails with a `NoSuchElementException`.

Instead you can use `flatMap` to perform your branching:

```
val actions = selectUserCountQuery1(user).flatMap {
  case 0 => for {
    status1 <- insertUserQuery(user)
    status2 <- insertPasswordQuery(passwordInfo)
    status3 <- insertSecurityTokenQuery(accessToken)
  } yield 0

  case n => DBIO.successful(n)
}

db.run(actions.transactionally).map {
  case 0 => Some(UserProfile.user2UserProfile(user, passwordInfo, accessToken))
  case _ => None
}
```